# Is it feasible to have multiple models for a single controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have just started working with rails, and I want to know whether it is possible to have multiple models for a single controller class? If yes, how can I achieve that?

I tried searching for the same but couldn't found much.

Comment: What do you mean - "models for controller"? You can use any models that you need in the controller. If you get stuck with some particular part of code, it is better to add code to the question

Comment: Yes, I meant the same. Thanks @Vasilisa

Comment: Yes it is possible with custom addressing & routes but it will not follow COC _(convention over configuration)_ which is not good. There must be strong reason to do it with some proper case up to limited extent.

Comment: Understood. Thanks ray